# Solving trigonometric differential equation $y''+y=\cos x-\sin x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I tried solving the equation using this method:

$$
y_p = A\sin{x} + B\cos{x} \\
y_p' = A\cos{x} - B\sin{x} \\
y_p'' = -A\sin{x} - B\cos{x}
$$

Then we subsitute y'' and y' with our particular solution:

$$
y''+y=\cos{x}-\sin{x} \\
-A\sin{x}-B\cos{x}+A\sin{x}+B\cos{x}=\cos{x}-\sin{x} \\
0 = \cos{x}-\sin{x}
$$

But what do I do next? What does $0 = \cos{x}-\sin{x}$ say about the solutions to the equation?

Comment: A remark: special functions have their own command, e.g., `$\sin$` gives $\sin$ which looks much nicer.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Thanks, reformatted it.

Comment: Since $ \ \sin x \ $ and $ \ \cos x \ $ already solve the homogeneous equation, you are going to need to step up to $ \ Ax \sin x \ $ and $ \ Bx \cos x \ $ in the particular solutuon.

Comment: Note that you can solve for $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ independently and then add the solutions.

Comment: Please do not use titles that are entirely MathJax.

Comment: @Lelouch Sorry not sure how to do this

Comment: @boojum Thanks but how I do then solve the substituted equation  $cosx(2A+2Bx)+sinx(A-2B+Ax) = cosx-sinx$? There are three unknown variables A, B and x.

Comment: You do not solve for $ \ x \ \ , \ $ since that is the independent variable.  You need to write the full expression for $ \ y''_p + y_p \ \ , \ $ in which you will find that the $ \ x \ \sin x \ $ and $ \ x \cos x \ $ terms "drop out" and the coefficients on $ \ \cos x \ $ and $ \ \sin x \ $ must match up with $ \ \cos x - \sin x \ \ . \ $